# Excel Solver VBA, Multiple dynamic input

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, cells, solver

I’m using the solver add-in for excel, I’m using it to optimize problem. However I’m running my head against a wall.

I must say I’m no pro at excel, so it might be a simple question, but I’ve searched the net for hours now, so I hope you can help me.

The variables set in ByChange needs to be something like:

`SolverOk SetCell:="$A$8", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$B$4”:”$B$12”, “$C$4”`

The problem is that “$B$12” can and will change all depending on another factor (nRow) that is including in the solving progress.

I have then been using this:

`ByChange:= .Range(Cells(4 , 2) , Cells(4+nRow , 2).Address`
But with this I cant seem to add cell “C4” to the list of variables, it keeps making an error and wont run my VBA Script.

I Hope you can help me.
Thank you very much

Best regards 
Peter Hansen

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: try adding & ", $C$4" after .Address